# Finding a particular string in HTML

Tags: html, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to extract data from a website and display it to the user. I'm recieving HTML, and I need to find a particular number inside it.

For example the string would be : "Canada = 50, USA = 60, France = 70". I need to search for "Canada" and find only the number 50.

I've been searching online for how to actually search the returned string of HTML and can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Try this link regarding parsing html: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching for keywords in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172034/iphone-ipad-html-search)

Comment: Thank you, the first link was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how this could be done in App since you want the App to look for specific words in a text file.

However I know this can be done using data analysis tools like R which can filter large amount of texts to create word clouds.

http://georeferenced.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/rwordcloud/